# Installing Older Docker Engine specifically - 1.11.0~dev

Tags: docker

Many of the article explains how to install a particular version of Docker. However, they are often quite old and not applicable (or somehow not working for me)

I would like to install Docker Engine 1.11.0~dev how can I do it?

Desired Version

```
Docker version 1.11.0-dev, build 79edcc5, experimental
```

Current Latest Version

```
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
```

Comment: Google it: https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.11.0

Comment: This is a release note, but it doesn't explain how to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing all sort of install steps, I realized the key is the exact version name to install. Here is how I eventually got it installed with the version I want.

## Experimental Repo

```
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty experimental" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9

$ sudo apt-get update

# This is the key step for me to find the exact package names to install
$ apt-cache policy docker-engine

$ sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.11.0~dev~git20160331.233925.0.4a7bd7e-0~trusty
```

## Sample output of policy

```
$ apt-cache policy docker-engine
     1.12.0~dev~git20160421.173724.0.6f67c13-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/experimental amd64 Packages
     1.12.0~dev~git20160420.164247.0.3022a43-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/experimental amd64 Packages
     1.11.0~dev~git20160406.072940.0.bb9b173-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/experimental amd64 Packages
     1.11.0~dev~git20160405.073835.0.8d31b0f-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/experimental amd64 Packages
```

## Main Repo

```
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

<... the rest is the same ...>
```

Comment: The question does not specifically mention debian. Please clarify to receive an upvote.